# Use of double left join in a query returns different values

Tags: mysql, function

Below are the tables

TABLE 1

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL
 )
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

TABLE 2

```
create table table2(
no int auto_increment primary key,
Reg_no  varchar(2),
debit decimal(19,2)
)
engine=innodb;
```

TABLE 3

```
 create table table3(
 no int auto_increment primary key,
 Reg_no  varchar(2),
 Paid decimal(19,2)
)
engine=innodb;
```

Please below is my query code.

```
SELECT id, sum(Paid) AS AMOUNT,sum(debit) AS DEBIT 
from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.Reg_no
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id=table3.Reg_no 
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Please I am finding it very difficult in using double left join in a query,the problem in this code is that,the sum used in the query above give more than the expected figure,for instance the `sum(10+10)` will output `40` instead of `20`. Please  where am I going wrong with my code.I would be grateful if anybody could help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each join is 1-many so you are multiplying the number of rows for each id.

The solution is to pre-aggregate the results.  However, you don't provide enough information in the question to give a correct answer.  The query probably looks something like:

```
SELECT id, Paid, Debit
from table1 LEFT JOIN
     (select Reg_no, sum(Debit) as Debit
      from table2
      group by Reg_no
     ) table2
     ON table1.id = table2.Reg_no left outer join
     (select Reg_no, sum(Paid) as Paid
      from table3
      group by Reg_no
     ) table3
     ON table1.id = table3.Reg_no 
order BY table1.id
```